# What does this error mean while starting package "export" in R?

Tags: r

I get this error when starting the `export` package in R.  It seems to download successfully, but when `library(export)` is run, I get this message:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘export’ in dyn.load(file,
>   DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):  unable to load shared object
>   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/gdtools/libs/gdtools.so':
>   dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/gdtools/libs/gdtools.so,
>   6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libcairo.2.dylib   Referenced
>   from:
>   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/gdtools/libs/gdtools.so
>   Reason: image not found

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @Eric, can you check if .dll is existing in the path mentioned in the error?

Comment: That suggests that you need to install X11 on your macOS. Try installing [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) and then try again.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  @MauritsEvers that solution worked!

Comment: You're very welcome @Eric, glad it worked out.